# AEM - JUnit testcase for query builder

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, aem, powermock

We have a business requirement where we query set of assets through a particular path and moving the expired assets from one folder to archive folder,
how can we write JUnit test case for below code,

```
@Reference
CommonConfigService commonConfigService ;
ResourceResolver resourceResolver ;
@Reference
QueryBuilder querybuilder;

private void queryForAssets()
{
    Session session = resourceResolver .adaptTo(Session .class);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("path", "myPath");
    map.put("type" ,"dam:Asset");
    map.put("property" ,"prism:ExpirationDate");
    final Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map),session);
    final SearchResults resultSet = query.getResult();
    for(Hit hit: resultSet.getHits())
    {
        //business logic,...iterating through each node path and reading the expiry date properties//
        moveAssetToDestination();
    }
}
```

In the above code , the last function `moveAssetToDestination()` will move all the expired assets from one folder to archive folder.
So basically there are no methods which are exactly returning any value.
Is it possible to write any JUnit for above code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to mock void methods, you typically can use Mockito's verify statements to verify that expected actions were invoked.  Take a look at this article for some examples:
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-void-methods

So if you look at what `moveAssetToDestination()` does, it likely calls methods on some sort of object. You can construct a test where that object on which the methods are called is a mock, and then you can use verify statements and argument catchers to validate that the method was invoked with expected parameters.

Or in the queryForAssets method you would make `queryBuilder` be a mock object using the `@Mock` annotation and `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.  See http://www.wemblog.com/2016/12/how-to-write-tests-in-aem.html for an example of that. Then you can set things up so that when its `createQuery` method is called it returns a mock Query object.  Then you could validate with a verify statement to verify that the getResult method is invoked on the mock object when you execute the code.  Similar things could be done for whatever objects are acted upon within the `moveAssetToDestination` method.